# Simple Detect Solution Causing Difficulties

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following code, which is supposed to provide a simple `true-false` wrapper over `Array#detect`, which is `nil-element`.

```
class Array
  def any &expr
    if (self.detect expr)
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

For some weird reason, no matter what is passed to `&expr`, it ALWAYS returns true! Why is this?

Comment: Array already has `any?` through `Enumerable`: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for Enumerable#detect says that it can optionally take one argument.  If it doesn't find the element that matched your block, it returns this argument.  In your case, you're passing a Proc object, `expr` to `detect`, and not passing a block.  This causes `detect` to return an enumerator, which won't be interpreted as a "falsy" value.

I think instead you want `self.detect &expr` to pass an actual block instead of a Proc.